# How best to automate a PowerQuery using VBA to create multiple tables from the same source data?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am currently working with a very large Excel file of invoices (I can't get it as not-excel since it's provided to me by an outside party) where I regularly need to go in and pull the invoices from a specific handful of invoices. My current VBA process looks like this:

```
Sub ResetWorkbook()

Dim InvoiceList As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim QueryInvoiceNumber As Range
Dim QueryInvoicePath As Range
Dim QueryFormula As Range
Dim InvoiceNumber As String


Set InvoiceList = Range("Invoice_Selections[Ref]")
Set QueryInvoiceNumber = Sheet3.Range("A5")
Set QueryInvoicePath = Sheet3.Range("A3")
Set QueryFormula = Sheet3.Range("A1")

QueryInvoicePath = Sheet1.Range("K2").Value


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
For Each c In InvoiceList

InvoiceNumber = c.Value
QueryInvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=InvoiceNumber, Formula:=QueryFormula.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "#" & InvoiceNumber
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & InvoiceNumber _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & InvoiceNumber & "]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True


  End With
    
    Next

  ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

And this is the PowerQuery language used:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("FILEPATH"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=59, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{HEADERS}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([HEADER] = "I6415622"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

For each invoice number in the list I need, the 'filtered rows' step in the above query is updated. The resulting list is then output to a new sheet.

The problem I'm running into is that the file I receive changes regularly - columns are added, moved, and removed. The critical columns I need are always there, but not always in the same place. Every time this happens I have to re-create the powerquery from scratch.

I know that PowerQuery does those first 3 steps automatically, and I know there is a much more elegant way to do this, but the best answer I've been able to find has broken links to some critical steps and I don't understand either #M or VBA well enough to be able to fill in the gaps. How do I set up this VBA so that I can call a dynamic table rather than having to change my code every time I get a new version of the file?

Comment: Is your data in a CSV file?  How large is "very large"?

Comment: "The critical columns I need are always there" - that's all Power Query wants to know and use. You need to specify them on the query steps so that the other (unusable?) columns are not loaded. I suggest you create a query "From Folder" obviously pointing to a folder, like your Font. Each new file is placed in, say, a new subfolder (Power Query does the recursive lookup in all subfolders) and your query will be updated with the new data by just one command: Refresh. And if these invoices are XML files, PQ also works fine, having a dedicated menu to handle them.

Comment: This YouTube video can explain it in detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMQK1Zcc9jw

Comment: @TimWilliams Unfortunately not - I wish it were but the person I get it from is not overwhelmingly technically savvy. They run in the 10k+ lines and big enough that saving takes 2-3 minutes

Comment: Your code has `Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("FILEPATH"),[Delimiter=",",` so that looks like a CSV to me?